# MYSQL-Access-Macro Error Unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am trying to run an Excel macro that imports data from a csv file into an Access database, MySQL front end. The macro code is not new-we've been using this for a couple of years, the table in the Access DB is not new, and the csv files with which the data is used to be brought into the Access table is also unchanged (meaning same rows, same data types).

I am stumped as the error appears to be something of an anomaly and I have tried several fixes to correct the error. I have attached a copy of the error as well as the code below. The issue with the column referenced below as well error message attached, "itemcode", this column is in the database.

Clearly, there is something that I am missing. Any insights are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
'Read in Current .csv file
'Data Services
 NumRows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
 For iCount = 1 To NumRows 
 Dim InstData(11)
 InstData(1) = Range("A" & iCount) 'Date
    invoiceDate = Format(InstData(1), "yyyy/mm/dd")
 InstData(2) = Range("B" & iCount) 'Invoice Number
 InstData(3) = Range("C" & iCount) 'names
    flname() = Split(InstData(3), ",")
    lname = flname(0)
    fname = flname(1)
 InstData(4) = Range("D" & iCount) 'Address1
 InstData(5) = Range("E" & iCount) 'Address2
 InstData(6) = Range("F" & iCount) 'City
 InstData(7) = Range("G" & iCount) 'State
 InstData(8) = Format(Range("H" & iCount), "00000") 'postal code
 InstData(9) = Range("I" & iCount) 'phone
 InstData(10) = Range("J" & iCount) 'email
 InstData(11) = Range("K" & iCount) 'amount

 Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
 Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
 conn.Open "Dsn=HERIpub"
rec.Open ("Insert into tbl_Invoice       (invoiceNumber,invoiceDate,invoiceAmount,invoiceDescription,invoiceFAU,invoiceCostCenter,invoiceProject,itemcode,invoicecFName,invoicecLName, invoicecAddr1, invoicecAddr2, invoicecCity, invoicecState, invoicecZIP, invoicecEmail, invoicecPhone) Values ('" & InstData(2) & "','" & invoiceDate & "','" & InstData(11) & "','Data Services','T6','T6','DATASL','40070DATASL','" & fname & "'" & ",'" & lname & "','" & InstData(4) & "', '" & InstData(5) & "', '" & InstData(6) & "', '" & InstData(7) & "', '" & InstData(8) & "', '" & InstData(10) & "', '" &  InstData(9) & "')"), conn
```

[macro error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3a73.png)

Comment: Clearly something has changed... verify that `itemcode` definitely exists, is long enough for the data and typed correctly.

Comment: MySQL frontend? Did you mean backend? And what is the error?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back to me. I didn't see the response. My mistake it's a MYSQL back end using ACCESS as a front end. I have verified the datatype as VARCHAR(25) and the number of characters to be brought into the field is 11.

Comment: The error is the script is failing at inserting ITEMCODE into the table. ITEMCODE is a field in the table and it is written out in the code. And I am not seeing the issue.

Comment: check itemcode field. Can you paste here your table tbl_Invoice structure?

Comment: Hello,  Thanks for the response.  This text box won't let me copy/paste the table structure.  I can write it out: Column Name: itemcode, Datatype: VARCHAR(25).  Does this help? Thanks again.

Comment: Check the Case-sensitive of the field itemcode.

Comment: Hi. I checked the table and I can't find any comments or notation that field itemcode is case sensitive.  Can you advise on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the variable fname , there you have redundant " & " . I think it should be:

```
rec.Open ("Insert into tbl_Invoice       (invoiceNumber,invoiceDate,invoiceAmount,invoiceDescription,invoiceFAU,invoiceCostCenter,invoiceProject,itemcode,invoicecFName,invoicecLName, invoicecAddr1, invoicecAddr2, invoicecCity, invoicecState, invoicecZIP, invoicecEmail, invoicecPhone) Values ('" & InstData(2) & "','" & invoiceDate & "','" & InstData(11) & "','Data Services','T6','T6','DATASL','40070DATASL','" & fname & "','" & lname & "','" & InstData(4) & "', '" & InstData(5) & "', '" & InstData(6) & "', '" & InstData(7) & "', '" & InstData(8) & "', '" & InstData(10) & "', '" &  InstData(9) & "')"), conn
```

Tell me if I'm right, or mark a vote up!

Comment: Thanks for that, I see where the redundant "&" was.  I tried running the the script with the new line. And I still get the same error.